# cast double to int without rounding

Tags: c

i don't understand why when i try to cast my double to int the values ​​after the commas are rounded..

```
void print_float(double nb)
{
    int negative;
    int intpart;
    double decpart = -10.754;
    int v;

    negative = (nb < 0.0f);
    intpart = (int)nb;
    decpart = nb - intpart;
    v = (int)(decpart * 1000);

    if (negative) {
        v *= -1;
    }

    printf("%i.%i", intpart, v); // output: -10.753
}
```

I guess after thinking that the worries come from the cast, but I do not understand the problem..

Comment: What do you envision that cast should do then?

Comment: An `ìnt` can't hold fractions. This comes from the definition of what an "integer" is in math and is kept that way in computer science. https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/integer.html

Comment: Note:a double has 53bits mantissa. (and a range that exceeds INT_MIN -- INT_MAX)

Comment: @wildplasser ... in the most common (IEEE) representation

Comment: @TobySpeight  yes. (I don't assume the OP is living on a VAX or a CRAY)

Comment: It is truncated, not rounded. If you need floating point, then why do you cast to fixed point?

Comment: it's truncated, and to obtain it rounded just do: `v = (int)(decpart * 1000. + 0.5);` - The OP would like to get 3 digits fractional part as an int. Some adjustment needed to handle negative numbers probably.

Comment: @Sigismondo This solution also works perfectly, i no understand the purpose of `+ 0.5`

Comment: since it works perfectly, what were you asking for??? I mean, with + 0.5 you get correct *rounding* instead of *truncation*

Comment: @Sigismondo `(int)(decpart * 1000. + 0.5)` fails for various cases; the worst of which when `decpart > 0.9995` as `10.9996` would print  as 10.1000.  It fails to round the right direction for -0.xxx5, Also fails the corner case of the value just below 0.5 due to rounding.

Comment: @7hsk To print a `double` with 3 places right of the decimal point, use `printf("%0.3f", nb);`.  Or is this code only for investigation purposes?

Comment: @chux I'm trying to replicate the fonction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `double` cannot exactly encoded all numbers.  It can exactly encoded about 2<sup>64</sup> different values.  `-10.754` is not one of them.  Instead a nearby value is used just less than expected.

```
printf("%.24f", -10.754);
// -10.753999999999999559463504
```

The `decpart * 1000` part introduces some imprecision yet the product is still below 754.0 and then the `(int)` cast makes that 753.